# Java compound interest calculation

Tags: java, math

my assignment is to calculate the number of years it takes to reach $5000 if you start with $2500 with 7.5% interest. The calculation should be 10 years, but it outputs 11 years. This might be a simple syntax error, but I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours with no luck.

```
final double principle = 2500.00;
double accrued = 0;
final double interest = 0.075;
int year = 0;
double interest1 = 1.0 + interest;
while (accrued < 5000.00)
{
  accrued = principle * Math.pow(interest1, year);
  year++;
}
System.out.printf("It would take %d years to reach at least $5000 if you start with $2,500 with 7.5%% compound interest.", year);
```

Comment: You should do some step-by-step debugging to see why this happens.

Comment: You are incrementing the year after you perform the calculation, try moving the increment to before the calculation.

Comment: @pstrjds That seemed to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
final double principle = 2500.00;
double accrued = 0;
final double interest = 0.075;
int year = 0;
double interest1 = 1.0 + interest;
while (accrued <  5000.00)
{
     year++;
     accrued = principle * Math.pow(interest1, year);
}
System.out.printf("It would take %d years to reach at least $5000 if you start with $2,500 with 7.5%% compound interest.", year);
```

Comment: Why did you change from the `year++`?  Whilst what you have shown should fix the problem, it would be more useful as an answer if you explained why this should fix it.

Comment: There was just an simple mistake in the logic. We should first increment the year. then assign the compounded value because of the while condition. And yes year = year +1 was done when I was debugging in my IDE :). year++ is much better

Comment: Right, it was just a simple mistake, but you have just dumped code (not correctly formatted btw) with no explanation.  It is best to add at least a minimal explanation as to why this would help/be the answer into your answer.

Comment: Yes I agree with you completely @pstrjds. I though it would be easier for him to take the corrected code  and try. And yes formatting is screwed once again due to my IDE :(